# Trying to capture _id after findOneAndUpdate upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using findOneAndUpdate with "upsert" for the first time. I'm replacing some ugly code I had initially.

I really like how clean the refactoring is, but one of my requirements is if a new record is created, I need to capture the _id for use in another process immediately following.

The problem is that if a record doesn't exist and it does an "upsert" the return is null.

I've tried returnNewDocument: true  & false but no luck.

Here is how my code is structured:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "user_email" : req.body.userEmail},
   { $set: { "property_1" : req.body.prop1, "property_2": req.body.prop2 } },      
{
   upsert: true,  
   returnNewDocument: true     
}, 
   function(err, data){
     if(err)
       console.log('Error in find one and update');

   console.log('Show data result: ', data);

})
```

I thought changing returnNewDocument to "false" would do the trick as it should return the original document, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks, All!!

Comment: Are you using `mongoose`? [It recognizes `new` instead of `returnNewDocument`.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: Also, next time you ask questions like this make sure that you clearly state the library you are using - in this case mongoose.

Comment: Thanks, maowtm. That looks like it did the trick. I thought Mongoose was inferred in the tagging. I'll make sure to explicitly state that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `mongoose`. [It recognizes the `new` option instead of mongodb's `returnNewDocument`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate).